# C++ - static Template no matching function

Tags: c++, templates

Before posting this, as I know It's may be a common problem, I've already read posts on StackOverflow and read about templates but I'm still not able to solve my problem.

I have a class Tool with one function inside.

**.h file**

```
class Tools{

public:
    template<typename T>
    static std::string tostr(const T& t);  

};
```

**.cpp file**

```
template<typename T>
std::string Tools::tostr(const T& t) {
    ostringstream os;
    os<<t;
    string res= os.str();
    return res;
}
```

The purpose of this function is to transform a number into a string (I know that the c++ 11 has already a function who does that but I would like to learn and to be more familiar with the concept)

In a another class, I use the function as the following:

```
 string resStr= Tools::tostr<string>("7.12341");
```

But I got this error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'Tools::tostr(float)'

Then I also tried this line:

```
 string resStr= Tools::tostr("7.12341");
```

And I got also an error :

> error: undefined reference to `std::string Tools::tostr(float
>   const&)'

I don't understand because I did the following verifications:

- I defined static in the .h file the function
- I put the `template<typename T>` to define the template (I also tried with `template<class T>`)
- The return type string is well defined
- The class Tool.h is well included in the class when I call the function

Any ideas ?

Thanks you all.

Answer (score -1):

Move the definition of `std::string Tools::tostr` into the header file.

Comment: In which header ? Where the function is or Where I use the function ? How I can do that ? Thanks.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @lilouch Move the definition of `std::string Tools::tostr` into the header file that you mentioned in your question. Most common way to move code from one file to a different file is by Cut&Paste.

Comment: @MohitJain I did plan to expand on that, but meanwhile R Sahu already marked the question as duplicate with a link to a perfectly fine explanation.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll read the post.